# Jetpack Compose - change a value immediately in the middle of animation

Tags: android, animation, android-jetpack-compose

I'm implementing a card flipping animation using Jetpack Compose, using the following implementation learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68044576/how-to-make-flipcard-animation-in-jetpack-compose).

```kotlin
// Generate card flipping animation transition
private class TransitionData(
    rotation: State<Float>,
) {
    val rotation by rotation
}

@Composable
private fun generateTransition(front: Boolean): TransitionData {
    val transition = updateTransition(front, label = "")

    val rotation = transition.animateFloat(
        transitionSpec = {
            tween(500)
        },
        label = ""
    ) { state ->
        when (state) {
            true -> 0f
            false -> 180f
        }
    }

    return remember(transition) { TransitionData(rotation) }
}


...
// the Composable code
val transitionData = generateTransition(lastCardState)

Image(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(15.dp)
        .graphicsLayer {
            rotationY = transitionData.rotation
            cameraDistance = 8 * density
        },
    painter = painterResource(card?.card_resource_id ?: R.drawable.fallback),
    contentDescription = "Card",
    contentScale = FixedScale(0.7f)
)
...
```

When `lastCardState` value changed, it does flip the image by animating the `rotationY` of `graphicsLayer`, but I also need to change the image during animation so it will display the card front image in the first 250ms and the back image in the second 250ms. In another way to say, `card_resource_id` is a resource ID of a drawable image, the value should be `1` in the first half of the animation and immediately change to `10` in the second half of the animation.

I can change the painter resource id by checking the value stored in `lastCardState`, but that will make the image change at the very first time of the animation (when the recomposition happens). Using `keyframes` seems to be able to set keyframe to animation, but it seems still not able to change a value immediately during the middle of the animation. Adding another int state and using `animateInt` to make it transition from `0` to `1` seems a little hack and not the correct way to do.

So how can I immediately change a value in the middle of animation in Jetpack Compose?

Edit: Thanks to Maciej Ciemięga, I just realized the card-flipping case can be implemented by simply checking the existing `rotation` state value! Although that's a more reasonable implementation for my case, I still would like to know how to change a value immediately in the middle of the animation as this question asked, for example at exactly 250ms. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You already have the `rotation` variable that you can use for this purpose. Painter can be conditionally changed e.g. `painter = if (rotation < 90f) frontPainter else backPainter`

Comment: Thanks and it works! Never realized I can use the `rotation` state directly! By the way, if I plan to change it at a specific time as I originally want to do (add a new state variable and change it immediately to another value at 250ms) instead of checking the rotation number, how can I achieve that?